# FHIR HL7 json structure

Tags: java, json, spring, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I just wanted to know the structure of FHIR HL7 when we have following information for same patient with difference addresses and compound drugs.
Reference id 
Execution or publication date
Precription1
Drug Name
Drug Strength
Prescription written date
Quantity
Dispenser name
Patient Name:
Patient DOB:
Patient Address:
Prescriber Name:
Prescriber Licence

Prescription2(compound drug: Drug A and B with different dosage and strength)
Drug Name
Drug Strength
Prescription written date
Quantity
Dispenser name
Patient Name:
Patient DOB:
Patient Address:(different from prescription 1)
Prescriber Name:
Prescriber Licence

How FHIR HL7 json structure would look like?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There are lots of ways of sharing that information - in a batch/transaction if you're trying to create the information using REST; in a document; in a message; as parameters to an operation.

Comment: Also, what is "execution or publication date"?  And what's the relationship between the two prescriptions?

Comment: I want to share this information as message. publication date is when we are sending this message to requestor. Both prescription are for a single patient, prescription 1 contains one medicine only and prescription 2 having compound drugs(contained 1+drugs)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that FHIR messaging works best in closed environments where a specific set of partners agree on what to share, what the event codes are, what responses are allowed, etc.

You'd have a FHIR Bundle starting with a MessageHeader entry.  It would also have entries for two MedicationRequests, Patient, two Medications and either one or two Practitioner resources (depending on whether the prescriber is the same for both).  The MedicationRequests and MessageHeader would both point to the Patient as the subject and the Practitioner(s) as requester and the Medications as the medication.  The MessageHeader would point to the two MedicationRequests as the message "focus". That should hopefully be enough to get you started.  (You can see example FHIR messages in XML and JSON here: http://hl7.org/fhir/message-request-link.html)

Comment: Thanks Llyod, you have explained very well. Where should I put dispenser details for each prescription?

Comment: Dispense is separate from prescription.  You could have multiple MedicationDispense resources for one MedicationRequest.  Each MedicationDispense would point to the Practitioner and/or Organization that performed the dispense.  The MedicationDispenses would also point to the Patient and back to the MedicationRequest that authorizes the dispense.